# Postfix Recipient address rejected: Access denied error after removing permit_mynetworks

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server, smtp-auth

I have a mail server which have to remove "permit_mynetworks" from Postfix configuration file(main.cf) in case of abuse. I only set it to allow SASL autheniented relay. But now, postfix would reject any foreign recipients. Can somebody please tell me what's wrong? Thanks in advance!

Here are the configurations:
[main.cf]

```
# --------------------
# INSTALL-TIME CONFIGURATION INFORMATION
#
# location of the Postfix queue. Default is /var/spool/postfix.
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix

# location of all postXXX commands. Default is /usr/sbin.
command_directory = /usr/sbin

# location of all Postfix daemon programs (i.e. programs listed in the
# master.cf file). This directory must be owned by root.
# Default is /usr/libexec/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix/sbin

# location of Postfix-writable data files (caches, random numbers).
# This directory must be owned by the mail_owner account (see below).
# Default is /var/lib/postfix.
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix

# owner of the Postfix queue and of most Postfix daemon processes.
# Specify the name of a user account THAT DOES NOT SHARE ITS USER OR GROUP ID
# WITH OTHER ACCOUNTS AND THAT OWNS NO OTHER FILES OR PROCESSES ON THE SYSTEM.
# In particular, don't specify nobody or daemon. PLEASE USE A DEDICATED USER.
# Default is postfix.
mail_owner = postfix

# The following parameters are used when installing a new Postfix version.
#
# sendmail_path: The full pathname of the Postfix sendmail command.
# This is the Sendmail-compatible mail posting interface.
#
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail

# newaliases_path: The full pathname of the Postfix newaliases command.
# This is the Sendmail-compatible command to build alias databases.
#
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases

# full pathname of the Postfix mailq command.  This is the Sendmail-compatible
# mail queue listing command.
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq

# group for mail submission and queue management commands.
# This must be a group name with a numerical group ID that is not shared with
# other accounts, not even with the Postfix account.
setgid_group = postdrop

# external command that is executed when a Postfix daemon program is run with
# the -D option.
#
# Use "command .. & sleep 5" so that the debugger can attach before
# the process marches on. If you use an X-based debugger, be sure to
# set up your XAUTHORITY environment variable before starting Postfix.
#
debugger_command =
    PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
    ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

debug_peer_level = 2

# --------------------
# CUSTOM SETTINGS
#

# SMTP server response code when recipient or domain not found.
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550

# Do not notify local user.
biff = no

# Disable the rewriting of "site!user" into "user@site".
swap_bangpath = no

# Disable the rewriting of the form "user%domain" to "user@domain".
allow_percent_hack = no

# Allow recipient address start with '-'.
allow_min_user = no

# Disable the SMTP VRFY command. This stops some techniques used to
# harvest email addresses.
disable_vrfy_command = yes

# Enable both IPv4 and/or IPv6: ipv4, ipv6, all.
inet_protocols = all

# Enable all network interfaces.
inet_interfaces = all

#
# TLS settings.
#
# SSL key, certificate, CA
#
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/iRedMail.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail.crt
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail.crt
smtpd_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs

#
# Disable SSLv2, SSLv3
#
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3

smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3

lmtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
lmtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3

#
# Fix 'The Logjam Attack'.
#
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, eNULL, EXPORT, DES, RC4, MD5, PSK, aECDH, EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA, EDH-RSA-DES-CDC3-SHA, KRB5-DE5, CBC3-SHA
smtpd_tls_dh512_param_file = /etc/ssl/dh512_param.pem
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /etc/ssl/dh2048_param.pem

tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom

# Log only a summary message on TLS handshake completion — no logging of client
# certificate trust-chain verification errors if client certificate
# verification is not required. With Postfix 2.8 and earlier, log the summary
# message, peer certificate summary information and unconditionally log
# trust-chain verification errors.
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1

# Opportunistic TLS: announce STARTTLS support to remote SMTP clients, but do
# not require that clients use TLS encryption.
smtpd_tls_security_level = may

# Produce `Received:` message headers that include information about the
# protocol and cipher used, as well as the remote SMTP client CommonName and
# client certificate issuer CommonName.
# This is disabled by default, as the information may be modified in transit
# through other mail servers. Only information that was recorded by the final
# destination can be trusted.
#smtpd_tls_received_header = yes

# Opportunistic TLS, used when Postfix sends email to remote SMTP server.
# Use TLS if this is supported by the remote SMTP server, otherwise use
# plaintext.
# References:
#   - http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#client_tls_may
#   - http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_security_level
smtp_tls_security_level = may

# Use the same CA file as smtpd.
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_CAfile = $smtpd_tls_CAfile
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes

# Enable long, non-repeating, queue IDs (queue file names).
# The benefit of non-repeating names is simpler logfile analysis and easier
# queue migration (there is no need to run "postsuper" to change queue file
# names that don't match their message file inode number).
enable_long_queue_ids = yes

# Reject unlisted sender and recipient
smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = no
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = no

# Header and body checks with PCRE table
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
body_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/body_checks.pcre

# A mechanism to transform commands from remote SMTP clients.
# This is a last-resort tool to work around client commands that break
# interoperability with the Postfix SMTP server. Other uses involve fault
# injection to test Postfix's handling of invalid commands.
# Requires Postfix-2.7+.
smtpd_command_filter = pcre:/etc/postfix/command_filter.pcre

# Relay restriction
smtpd_relay_restrictions =
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject

# HELO restriction
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    check_helo_access pcre:/etc/postfix/helo_access.pcre
    reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
    reject_unknown_helo_hostname

# Sender restrictions
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    permit_mynetworks
    check_sender_access pcre:/etc/postfix/sender_access.pcre
    reject

# Recipient restrictions
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    permit_mynetworks
    check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:12340
    reject_unauth_destination

# END-OF-MESSAGE restrictions
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions =
    check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777

# Data restrictions
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining

# SRS (Sender Rewriting Scheme) support
#sender_canonical_maps = tcp:127.0.0.1:7778
#sender_canonical_classes = envelope_sender
#recipient_canonical_maps = tcp:127.0.0.1:7779
#recipient_canonical_classes= envelope_recipient,header_recipient

proxy_read_maps = $canonical_maps $lmtp_generic_maps $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $mynetworks $recipient_bcc_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relay_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relocated_maps $sender_bcc_maps $sender_canonical_maps $smtp_generic_maps $smtpd_sender_login_maps $transport_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $smtpd_sender_restrictions $sender_dependent_relayhost_maps

# Avoid duplicate recipient messages. Default is 'yes'.
enable_original_recipient = no

# Virtual support.
virtual_minimum_uid = 2000
virtual_uid_maps = static:2000
virtual_gid_maps = static:2000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail

# Do not set virtual_alias_domains.
virtual_alias_domains =

#
# Enable SASL authentication on port 25 and force TLS-encrypted SASL authentication.
# WARNING: NOT RECOMMENDED to enable smtp auth on port 25, all end users should
#          be forced to submit email through port 587 instead.
#
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes

# hostname
myhostname = mail.ads-network.top
myorigin = mail.ads-network.top
mydomain = mail.ads-network.top

# trusted SMTP clients which are allowed to relay mail through Postfix.
#
# Note: additional IP addresses/networks listed in mynetworks should be listed
#       in iRedAPD setting 'MYNETWORKS' (in `/opt/iredapd/settings.py`) too.
#       for example:
#
#       MYNETWORKS = ['xx.xx.xx.xx', 'xx.xx.xx.0/24', ...]
#
mynetworks = 127.0.0.1 [::1]

# Accepted local emails
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, localhost.localdomain

alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases

# Default message_size_limit.
message_size_limit = 15728640

# The set of characters that can separate a user name from its extension
# (example: user+foo), or a .forward file name from its extension (example:
# .forward+foo).
# Postfix 2.11 and later supports multiple characters.
recipient_delimiter = +

# The time after which the sender receives a copy of the message headers of
# mail that is still queued. Default setting is disabled (0h) by Postfix.
#delay_warning_time = 1h

# Do not display the name of the recipient table in the "User unknown" responses.
# The extra detail makes trouble shooting easier but also reveals information
# that is nobody elses business.
show_user_unknown_table_name = no
compatibility_level = 2
#
# Lookup virtual mail accounts
#
transport_maps =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_user.cf
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_maillist.cf
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_domain.cf

sender_dependent_relayhost_maps =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_dependent_relayhost_maps.cf

# Lookup table with the SASL login names that own the sender (MAIL FROM) addresses.
smtpd_sender_login_maps =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_login_maps.cf

virtual_mailbox_domains =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf

relay_domains =
    $mydestination
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/relay_domains.cf

virtual_mailbox_maps =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf

virtual_alias_maps =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_alias_maps.cf
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_maps.cf
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/catchall_maps.cf
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_catchall_maps.cf

sender_bcc_maps =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_domain.cf

recipient_bcc_maps =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_user.cf
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_domain.cf

#
# Postscreen
#
postscreen_greet_action = drop
postscreen_blacklist_action = drop
postscreen_dnsbl_action = drop
postscreen_dnsbl_threshold = 2

# Attention:
#   - zen.spamhaus.org free tire has 3 limits
#     (https://www.spamhaus.org/organization/dnsblusage/):
#
#     1) Your use of the Spamhaus DNSBLs is non-commercial*, and
#     2) Your email traffic is less than 100,000 SMTP connections per day, and
#     3) Your DNSBL query volume is less than 300,000 queries per day.
#
#   - FAQ: "Your DNSBL blocks nothing at all!"
#     https://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/DNSBL%20Usage#261
#
# It's strongly recommended to use a local DNS server for cache.
postscreen_dnsbl_sites =
    zen.spamhaus.org=127.0.0.[2..11]*3
    b.barracudacentral.org=127.0.0.2*2

postscreen_dnsbl_reply_map = texthash:/etc/postfix/postscreen_dnsbl_reply
postscreen_access_list = permit_mynetworks cidr:/etc/postfix/postscreen_access.cidr

# Require Postfix-2.11+
postscreen_dnsbl_whitelist_threshold = -2

#
# Dovecot SASL support.
#
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1

#
# mlmmj - mailing list manager
#
mlmmj_destination_recipient_limit = 1

#
# Amavisd + SpamAssassin + ClamAV
#
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024

# Concurrency per recipient limit.
smtp-amavis_destination_recipient_limit = 1000
relayhost =
```

[master.cf]

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
#submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       y       -       -       qmqpd
#smtp       inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
pickup     unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
    -o content_filter=smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026
cleanup    unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
relay      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
    -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
showq      unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
postlog    unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu
    user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fqhu
    user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=F user=ftn
    argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fq.
    user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe flags=R
    user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop}
    ${user} ${extension}

mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=FR
    user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop}
    ${user}
# Submission, port 587, force TLS connection.
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o content_filter=smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026

# smtps, port 465, force SSL connection.
465 inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o content_filter=smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026

# Use dovecot's `deliver` program as LDA.
dovecot unix    -       n       n       -       -      pipe
    flags=DRh user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${domain} -m ${extension}

# mlmmj - mailing list manager
# ${nexthop} is '%d/%u' in transport ('mlmmj:%d/%u')
mlmmj   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=ORhu user=mlmmj:mlmmj argv=/usr/bin/mlmmj-amime-receive -L /var/vmail/mlmmj/${nexthop}

# Amavisd integration.
smtp-amavis unix -  -   n   -   4  smtp
    -o syslog_name=postfix/amavis
    -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
    -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
    -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
    -o max_use=20

# smtp port used by Amavisd to re-inject scanned email back to Postfix
127.0.0.1:10025 inet n  -   n   -   -  smtpd
    -o syslog_name=postfix/10025
    -o content_filter=
    -o mynetworks_style=host
    -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
    -o local_recipient_maps=
    -o relay_recipient_maps=
    -o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes
    -o smtp_tls_security_level=none
    -o smtpd_tls_security_level=none
    -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
    -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
    -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
    -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
    -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
    -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
    -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
    -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_address_mappings

# smtp port used by mlmmj to re-inject scanned email back to Postfix, with
# address mapping support
127.0.0.1:10028 inet n  -   n   -   -  smtpd
    -o syslog_name=postfix/10028
    -o content_filter=
    -o mynetworks_style=host
    -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
    -o local_recipient_maps=
    -o relay_recipient_maps=
    -o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes
    -o smtp_tls_security_level=none
    -o smtpd_tls_security_level=none
    -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
    -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
    -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
    -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
    -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
    -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
    -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks
```

Also, here is the DIAG reported by postfix:

```
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554 5.7.1 id=17953-16 - Rejected by next-hop MTA on
    relaying, from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 554 5.7.1
    <******@outlook.com>: Recipient address rejected: Access denied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the look of your master.cf, you have a smtpd daemon listening on port 10025
to retrieve amavis scanned e-mails:

```
# smtp port used by mlmmj to re-inject scanned email back to Postfix, with
# address mapping support
127.0.0.1:10028 inet n  -   n   -   -  smtpd
```

This daemon on port 10025 requires SASL, as you described and as your log tells us:

```
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

your log:

```
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554 5.7.1 id=17953-16 - Rejected by next-hop MTA on
relaying, from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 554 5.7.1
<******@outlook.com>: Recipient address rejected: Access denied
```

That being said, **amavis does not use SASL** so it is rejected.

I suggest you allow at least the loopback IP address 127.0.0.1 for that specific daemon. Doing so does not cause much risk.

Also, since you are running amavis on the same server as postfix, you can optimize things by using a linux socket instead.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! Basically, it is safe to allow localhost, but in my case it would be dangerous because there is a reverse proxy running on the server. Any request will be forwarded from the proxy to port 25, and the proxy itself is a localhost instance. Allowing them already resulted in 70K scam mails queued. I wonder if I can force amavis to use SASL or make postfix only assume a range of ports as "mynetworks".

Comment: there seems to be a misunderstanding, in master.cf, you can override the  smtpd_recipient_restrictions to add back mynetworks to the 10025 while leaving the main.cf with forced sasl

Comment: I finally get it! I didn't realize that configurations in master.cf can override settings in main.cf, and when I added "-o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_mynetworks, reject", it worked like a charm! Thanks for your kind hint :-)